# Django, How do I write views when form submission using ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a model here

```
class personaldetails(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mbleno=models.IntegerField()
    maritalstatus=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    currentindustry=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    functionalarea=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    annualsalary=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def personalinformation(request):
    print "hello"
    if request.method=='POST':
        print "hi"
        fn=request.POST.get('fname')
        print fn
        ln=request.POST.getlist('lname')
        email=request.POST.getlist('email')
        mno=request.POST.getlist('mbleno')
        ms=request.POST.getlist('maritalstatus')
        ci=request.POST.getlist('currentindustry')
        fc=request.POST.getlist('functionalarea')
        ans=request.POST.getlist('annualsalary')
        personaldetails(fname=fn,lname=ln,email=email,mbleno=mno,maritalstatus=ms,currentindustry=ci,functionalarea=fc,annualsalary=ans).save()
        s="example"
        return HttpResponse(s,mimetype='application/json')
    return render(request,"itechdisplay.html")
```

my itechdisplay.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formid').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
         type:$(this).attr('method'),
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        url:'/personalinformation/',
        success:function(data) {
        alert($(data));
}
  });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="." id="formid" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

Firstname:<input type="text" id="firstname" name="input1"><br>
Lastname:<input type="text" id="lastname" name="input2"><br>
e-mail:<input type="text" id="email" name="input4"><br>
mobileno:<input type="text" id="mobleno" name="input5"><br>
Maital status:<select id="maritalstatus">
<option value="s1" selected>single</option>
<option value="s1">married</option>
<option value="s1">divorsed</option>
<option value="s1">other</option>
</select><br>
Current industry<select id="currentindustry">
<option value="s1">IT-software/software sevices</option>
<option value="s1" selected>it-hardware/networking</option>
<option value="s1">insurance</option>
<option value="s1">other</option>
</select><br>
Functional area:<select id="functionalarea">
<option value="s1" selected>IT-software</option>
<option value="s1">it-hardware</option>
<option value="s1">agent</option>
<option value="s1">other</option>
</select><br>
Annual salary<select id="annualsalary">
<optgroup label="Hour wise">
<option value="s1">less than 40$/hr</option>
<option value="s1">40-50$/hr</option>
<option value="s1">50-60$/hr</option>
<option value="s1">above 60$</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="month wise">
<option value="s1">less than 20,000$</option>
<option value="s1">20-30,000$</option>
<option value="s1">30-40,0000$</option>
<option value="s1">above 40,000$</option>
</optgroup>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" id="save1" value="save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written a model.
In my template I want to use post method. When I submit a form I want the details to be moved to views and store it in the database and retrieve it to be displayed. I don't know know how to write the views to bring the data from template. I tried as I mentioned above.
But I get this error as follows

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

in a following line of my views.py

```
personaldetails(fname=fn,lname=ln,email=email,mbleno=mno,maritalstatus=ms,currentindustry=ci,functionalarea=fc,annualsalary=ans).save()
```

How to write the view? Any approaches can be appreciated.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version not utilizing your models (I'll leave that up to you as an exercise)

```
def my_ajax_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            //do you logic here
            response_data = {'success': 'weee'}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

This is how you write a normal function ajax view.
Now to the errors that you're having.
Firstly I would recommend you not naming your variables `mc, mmo, ans, ci` or `func`, basically this makes it 100 times harder for anyone (even you cause you'll forget in a day what you wrote) to debug.

Secondly you're using `getlist()` on the `POST`. This will give you a list containing the information and when you try to save it your IntegerField `mbleno` is expecting an integer or string instead of a list.

I would try to switch

```
mno=request.POST.getlist('mbleno')
```

to

```
mno=request.POST.get('mbleno')
```

which most likely will give you other errors, but it's a good start!

Comment: it is not getting entered into request.is_ajax()

Comment: yes I have changed it like you said.. But it is not bringing the values from templates to views. I shows the error-(1048, "Column 'fname' cannot be null") in my views(first line after if loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Am getting